# linux IPC message space calculation

Tags: linux, ipc, message-queue

On Unix os'es (SVR4, UnixWare, etc.) the sizing of the IPC message queue space was governed by the following kernel tuneables:

MSGMAP
MSGMAX
MSGMNB
MSGMNI
MSGSSZ
MSGTQL
MSGSEG

As I understand from reading the old SVR4 and UnixWare online docs I can still find, to get the total amount of message queue space available for messages IN TOTAL, you do the following calculation:

MSGSEG * MSGSSZ

ie: the number of message segments in the system * by the size of each segment.  From the result of this equation, the collective total of messages currently in queue to all message queues CANNOT exceed this total.

Now, onto Linux oses...

In Linux (2.6 kernel), the IPC message queue space is now controlled by just:

MSGMNB
MSGMAX
MSGMNI

To do the same calculation as was done for SVR4/UnixWare, you would do:

MSGMNB * MSGMNI

Is this correct or am I missing something??